# interfaces for templated classes

Tags: c++, inheritance, templates

I'm working on a plugin framework, which supports multiple variants of a base plugin class `CPlugin : IPlugin`. I am using a `boost::shared_ptr<IPlugin>` for all reference to the plugins, except when a subsystem needs the plugin type's specific interface. I also need the ability to clone a plugin into another seprate object. This must return a `PluginPtr`. This is why `CPlugin` is a template rather than a straight class. `CPlugin::Clone()` is where the template paramter is used. The following are the class definitions I am using:

**IPlugin.h**

```
#include "PluginMgr.h"
class IPlugin;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<IPlugin> PluginPtr;

class IPlugin
{
public:
  virtual PluginPtr Clone() =0;
  virtual TYPE Type() const =0;
  virtual CStdString Uuid() const =0;
  virtual CStdString Parent() const =0;
  virtual CStdString Name() const =0;
  virtual bool Disabled() const =0;

private:
  friend class CPluginMgr;
  virtual void Enable() =0;
  virtual void Disable() =0;
};
```

**CPlugin.h**

```
#include "IPlugin.h"
template<typename Derived>
class CPlugin : public IPlugin
{
public:
  CPlugin(const PluginProps &props);
  CPlugin(const CPlugin&);
  virtual ~CPlugin();
  PluginPtr Clone();

  TYPE Type() const { return m_type; }
  CStdString Uuid() const { return m_uuid; }
  CStdString Parent() const { return m_guid_parent; }
  CStdString Name() const { return m_strName; }
  bool Disabled() const { return m_disabled; }

private:
  void Enable() { m_disabled = false; }
  void Disable() { m_disabled = true; }

  TYPE        m_type;
  CStdString  m_uuid;
  CStdString  m_uuid_parent;
  bool        m_disabled;
};

template<typename Derived>
PluginPtr CPlugin<Derived>::Clone()
{
  PluginPtr plugin(new Derived(dynamic_cast<Derived&>(*this)));
  return plugin;
}
```

**An example concrete class CAudioDSP.h**

```
#include "Plugin.h"
class CAudioDSP : CPlugin<CAudioDSP>
{
  CAudioDSP(const PluginProps &props);
  bool DoSomethingTypeSpecific();
  <..snip..>
};
```

My problem (finally) is that `CPluginMgr` needs to update `m_disabled` of the concrete class, however as it is passed a `PluginPtr` it has no way to determine the type and behave differently according to the template paramater. I can't see how to avoid declaring `::Enable()` and `::Disable()` as private members of `IPlugin` instead but this instantly means that every section of the application now needs to know about the `CPluginMgr` class, as it is declared as a friend in the header. Circular dependancy hell ensues. I see another option, declare the Enable/Disable functions as private members of CPlugin and use `boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<CVariantName>` instead.

```
void CPluginMgr::EnablePlugin(PluginPtr plugin)
{
  if(plugin->Type == PLUGIN_DSPAUDIO)
  {
    boost::shared_ptr<CAudioDSP> dsp = boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<CAudioDSP>(plugin);
    dsp->Enable();
  }
}
```

This however leads to lots of duplicate code with many multiple variants of the base `CPlugin` template. If anyone has a better suggestion please share it!

Comment: why is `CPlugin` templated? you should know that a class can be a non-template but have a templated member function (in this case clone).

Comment: Maybe I'm mising something, but can't you just do: `plugin->Enable();` if plugin is of type `PluginPtr`?. That's kind of the point of interfaces...

Comment: I don't want any class other than CPluginMgr to be able to disable/enable plugins

Comment: You're right I should just make CPlugin::Clone a template function instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily write :

```
class CPluginMgr;

class IPlugIn ..
{
    friend CPluginMgr;
    ...
};
```

Only a predefinition is needed for friend.

Comment: I can't believe it's so simple, yet it is :)
Thanks Christopher!

Answer (score 0):

I think your get in trouble trying to return a shared_ptr in clone method. Why don't you make use of  ***covariant return types***? What you are doing is a common idiom called **[Virtual Constructor](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.8)**.

```
class IPlugin
{
public:
    virtual IPlugin* clone() = 0;
    // ...
}

class CPluginMgr;

class CPlugin : public IPlugin
{
public:
    virtual CPlugin* clone() = 0;
    friend CPluginMgr; // as @Christopher pointed out
    void Enable(bool enable) { m_disabled = !enable; }
    // ...
}

class CAudioDSP : public CPlugin 
{
public:
    virtual CAudioDSP* clone();
    // ...
}

CAudioDSP* CAudioDSP::clone()
{
    return new CAudioDSP(*this); // assume copy constructors are properly implemented
}
```

Returning a shared_ptr may lead you to make errors (as early destruction of temparary objects) and I think is not usually a good idea.